# Log4j2: Is it possible to convert JSON string in map message value to structured JSON in event output?

Tags: java, logging, gson, log4j2

we're migrating from a custom logging framework to Log4j2 and trying to match output parity as best we can.

We currently have a log statement that accepts several parameters via a Map, and all of these properties get written to the root of our custom JSON logging output. Most of the map properties we're logging are primitives/strings, however one property is a `JsonElement` (Gson), and represents structured web request content. In our legacy custom logging framework it was written such that this `JsonElement` became grafted into the log output as a nested JSON object, so:

```
"request":{
      "visitId":"ABCDEFG"
   },
```

To try to replicate all of this functionality in Log4j2 I using `JsonTemplateLayout` with a resolver like so to flatten all the map (`StringMapMessage`) properties to the JSON root:

```
  "mapMessage": {
    "$resolver": "map",
    "flatten": true
  },
```

All I'm really doing to populate the Log4j2 event is to iterate through the Map and build out a `StringMapMessage` with the same content as before.

This seems to give us most of what we're looking for, except for dealing with the `JsonElement`. Log4j2 presumably (and understandably) just toString()'s the `JsonElement`. And so we end up with:

```
"request":"{\"visitId\":\"ABCDEFG\"}",
```

While I don't like passing this `JsonElement` on to Log4j2 like this I don't really see much option based on where in the code we're logging and the fact that this JsonElement object could represent a variety of different Java-backed Request objects in our system.

**Question: Is there a way for some behavior in the `JsonTemplateLayout` to deserialize the JSON string from this map field back into structured JSON? Or is there a different way I should be formatting my logging event to achieve this?**

I've tried things like the following:

in log4j2.xml:

```
                <EventTemplateAdditionalField
                        key="request"
                        format="JSON"
                        value='{"$resolver": "map", "field": "request"}'/>/>
```

in our template:

```
  "request": {
    "$resolver": "map",
    "key": "request",
    "format": "JSON",
    "stringified": false
  },
```

But no dice. Appreciate any and all help, thanks for looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using the current set of JTL resolvers. Though you can create your own resolver and render the `request` field there. See the [Extending Event Resolvers](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html#extending-event-resolvers) section in the manul. There your `EventResolver#resolve(LogEvent, JsonWriter)` method will have access to both the event itself and the buffer JSON is written into.

For the records, there is also [LOG4J2-3082](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3082). There I want to enable the customization of the employed `JsonWriter`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In the interim we actually ended up creating a resolver in line with what you're describing. I think there's added complexity in our use-case where we're flattening the map message generically in a JSON template is used by a few different loggers. So having a "request" specific resolver means we have duplicative content in some contexts, or an irrelevant "request" field in others. But I think we have a path forward.

Applicate your work on LOG4J2-3082. Would you happen to know if there's a way to exclude specified fields from a map message via template config?

Comment: `pattern` accepts a regex, which you can employ to exclude too, e.g., `"pattern": "(?!ignoreMe)"`.